# Run elastic search raw query with Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to run a raw query with Nest.Net library on elastic search. 
The query is as follow:

```
var json4 = @"
                    {
                      ""query"": {
                        ""bool"": {
                                    ""filter"":{
                                        ""term"":{ ""schoolId"": ""c15677ea-3e1e-4767-936a-2b3c57b00503""}
                                    },
                          ""must"": [
                            {
                              ""multi_match"": {
                                ""query"": ""001 Ali"",
                                ""fields"": [""firstName"",""lastName"", ""phoneNumber"",  ""code"", ""title""],
                                ""type"":  ""cross_fields""
                              }
                    }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
            ";

        SearchRequest searchRequest;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json4)))
        {
            searchRequest = client.RequestResponseSerializer.Deserialize<SearchRequest>(stream);
        }
```

The Deserialize method raise an error as follow:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Nest.QueryContainer]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'query.bool.filter.term', line 6, position 51.

The query is running in kibana just fine.

Thanks

Comment: what version of NEST?

Comment: the version is 5.6.0

Comment: 5.6.0 doesn't have  `RequestResponseSerializer` property on `IElasticClient`. Are you using a 6.x version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NEST deserialization supports only the long form of queries i.e.

- `bool` query `filter` clause must be an array of queries; it doesn't support passing an object where the keys of the object are queries
- `term` query short form of `"term": { "field": "value" }` is not supported; it must be of the form `"term": { "field" : { "value": "value" } }`.

The following would work

```
var json4 = @"
    {
      ""query"": {
        ""bool"": {
          ""filter"":[
            { ""term"":{ ""schoolId"": { ""value"": ""c15677ea-3e1e-4767-936a-2b3c57b00503""}} }
          ],
          ""must"": [
            {
              ""multi_match"": {
                ""query"": ""001 Ali"",
                ""fields"": [""firstName"",""lastName"", ""phoneNumber"",  ""code"", ""title""],
                ""type"":  ""cross_fields""
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
";

SearchRequest searchRequest;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json4)))
{
    searchRequest = client.Serializer.Deserialize<SearchRequest>(stream);
}
```

***BUT***, NEST is capable of accepting a query as a JSON string and returning a strongly typed search response using the low level client exposed as the `.LowLevel` property. With this, there's no need to deserialize the JSON string into a `SearchRequest`, only to serialize back to JSON when submitting the request. Additionally, you can use the original query you have

```
var json4 = @"
    {
      ""query"": {
        ""bool"": {
          ""filter"": { 
            ""term"":{ ""schoolId"": ""c15677ea-3e1e-4767-936a-2b3c57b00503"" } 
          },
          ""must"": [
            {
              ""multi_match"": {
                ""query"": ""001 Ali"",
                ""fields"": [""firstName"",""lastName"", ""phoneNumber"",  ""code"", ""title""],
                ""type"":  ""cross_fields""
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
";

client.LowLevel.Search<SearchResponse<object>>("index", "type", json4);
```